# Call a c++ function of SO file from python

Tags: python, c++

I Have an SO file which created for the following project (for example)
-Foo folder which contains files

- foo1.cpp, which contains function : sum(int number,int number2) // returns the sum of two numbers
- foo2.cpp

I would like to call the sum function from python file.

I wrote example which works for reading from c file( using  the [tutorial](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/lesson-parallel-python/08-calling_external_C_libraries/index.html)).

how can I use it for the c++ project?
I prefare not to change the so file.

```
    import ctypes
    testlib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./libtest.so")
    num_pow = testlib.num_pow
    num_pow.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long]
    num_pow.restype = ctypes.c_long
    high=2
    brute_force_num_pow=num_pow(high)
    print(int(brute_force_num_pow))
```

any suggestions where to start?

Comment: I'd start by searching the internet: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+call+C%2B%2B+function+from+shared+object In any case, you have an approach there already, so what's the problem with it?

Comment: What is an `SO` file?  What is the format?

Comment: An .so file is a compiled library file. It stands for "Shared Object" and is analogous to a Windows DLL.